# Access image from PhotoLibrary using UIImagepicker without User interaction?

Tags: iphone

Hi is it possible to access an image from the photolibrary without the user interaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asset Libraries and Blocks:

http://icodeblog.com/2010/07/08/asset-libraries-and-blocks-in-ios-4/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+icodeblog+%28iCodeBlog%29